# error : invalid byte sequence for encoding UTF8: 0xfa

Tags: java, select, urlencoding

Buen día. Estoy realizando una aplicación de escritorio escrita en java, necesito realizar un simple select a una base de datos posgrestsql, al intentar realizar la consulta me tira la siguiente excepción : 'invalid byte sequence for encoding UTF8: 0xfa'. Revisando en el algunos de los campos de la tabla donde quiero consultar hay caracteres con tildes de esta manera : "ú" y creo que el problema va por allí. De mi parte no tengo derechos para modificar nada en dicha tabla ni tampoco para cambiar el encoding de la base de datos que es SQL_ASII. Algunas soluciones que he encontrado en internet, lo que hacen es pasar el el resulset devuelto por la consulta a un arreglo de bytes para luego trabajar con el, intente hacer esto pero no me funciono, ya que la excepción me la esta mandando al hacer el "myStatement.executeQuery(query);", de tal manera que no me alcanza a devolver nada cuando marca el error.

```
        OpenConexion();
        myStatement = connection.createStatement();
        myStatement.executeQuery(query);          //  <- aqui marca el error
```

No he podido encontrar ninguna solucion ha este error, podria alguien ayudar? gracias.

Comment: a veces sale ese error con librerías viejas